# Backbone model default values : null ? empty string ? empty array?

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, backbone.js

In my Backbone app, models are instantiated when I retrieve data from an HTTP JSON API. Values vary from this service, so I decided for consistency to provide `defaults` so all the models share at least the same base attributes. Useful for templating for instance.

I'm just wondering : what's the best value to assign to each attribute ? Some will be strings, some numbers, others arrays. Not sure if I should assign `null` by default for everyone (this is what I'm doing now), or if I should use the empty string `""` for future strings and the empty array `[]` for future arrays.

Comment: It depends what you need. For example, if you have a date field, you could use the current Time for default. With arrays it would use ``[]``. Strings could be null or ``""``, what you prefer to check (``str==""`` or ``typeof str=="undefined"``)

Comment: I'll use the models attributes mainly in the templates (using Handlebars), so I only need to check for falsiness of the values. Current time is not an option in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually assign `null` values. I'm unlikely to use `null` as an actual value to pass around so if something in my application remains `null` I can tell that something went wrong somewhere.

By the way be careful when assigning empty arrays or objects via the `defaults` attribute. When you do this the array/object is referenced in each instance, instead of copied to each instance, of your model so they will all modify the same data.

Comment: Not sure I get your second paragraph : are you saying that, somehow, creating an empty array/object creates a single value in memory that gets pointed to by each instance when created ? I see in backbone source code (0.9.2) in line 300 that the assignment is done like `options.unset ? delete now[attr] : now[attr] = val;` (it's the now[attr] = val that really add the value to the instance). So you're saying that if I create an empty array/object, this very empty array/object will get referenced by each and every model of my collection when instantiated ?

Comment: @DjebbZ: If you `defaults: { a: [ ] }` then the same default array will be shared by all instances that use the default, the defaults are shallowed copied. However, you can say `defaults: function() { return { a: [ ] } }` to get distinct defaults for each instance. Generally you'll want to use the function form of defaults if any of the values are mutable objects.

Comment: Thanks guys, in my case I'll stick to `null`. I won't need the `function` form of `defaults` since it's full of `null` values. By the way, if were to use the function form like @muistooshort said, does it mean that if property `a` is not overridden when the model is instantiated my program will have a heavier memory footprint ?